# Android Yahoo and Hotmail clients not attaching images

Tags: android, email

This code works perfectly for the GMail Client, but for Yahoo and Hotmail, it only shows message, not attachment.

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", address, null));
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(uriString));
c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, title));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557651/android-cant-attach-file-to-email-in-non-gmail-client

Comment: but not answered. I want filteration of email clients too.

Comment: I guess the answer is: not consistent across all vendors, therefore not feasible.